# the use case for ranking documents in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I have use case in which documents in solr are like this:

{
    “movieName”:”black cat and rat”,
    “likes”:10
}

{
    “movieName”:”black cat is beautiful”,
    “likes”:100
}

{
    “movieName”:”black cat and dog”,
    “likes”:89
}

{
    “movieName”:”black cat and hat”,
    “likes”:90
}

Now when user searches for “black cat” or “cat” then the ranking of the documents should happen based on the likes,
e.g: somebody searches for “black cat” then Solr should rank,

{
    “movieName”:”black cat is beautiful”,
    “likes”:100
}

First, as it has maximum likes.

Now, suppose somebody searches for  “black cat and rat” then it should come first as there is a complete match and document,
{
    “movieName”:”black cat and rat”,
    “likes”:10
}

Should be ranked first despite having less likes.

Field definition in Managed-schema file is:

```
<field name=" movieName " type="text_general_sv" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: How do you want a title named "black cat and cat and cat" to be ranked compared to "black cat and dog", and how do you want "black cat" to be ranked compared to "black cat and dog"? If these are to be ranked equally (and then by likes as the second dimension), using `omitTermFreqAndPositions` for that field and then sorting by `score, likes` should work. It'll break phrase search, so if you need that, either use a separate field for those and use a `fq` or create a custom similarity.

Comment: "black cat and cat and cat" and "black cat and dog" should be ranked according to their likes but in case of "black cat" and "black cat and dog", "black cat" should come first as its a complete match(if we search for "black cat")